# How to implement stripe webhook in symfony 5?

Tags: webhooks, symfony5, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe in my symfony project for subscriptions, the subscription to plans from stripe and payment it works just fine, but the problem is that i couldn't implement the webhook in the right way  so i can know if a subscription is created, payed etc.

what i have done so far:
in my subscription controller i created the route to the webhook:

```php
class SubscriptionController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * webhook  page
     *
     * @Route("/bonsai_webhook",name="webhookPage")
     */
    public function bonsai_webook(Request $request,Response $response){
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_...');
        $webhookSecret = "whsec_...";
        $event = $request->query;
        // Parse the message body and check the signature
        $signature = $request->headers->get('stripe-signature');
        if ($webhookSecret) {
            try {
                $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
                    $request->getcontent(),
                    $signature,
                    $webhookSecret
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return new JsonResponse([['error' => $e->getMessage(),'status'=>403]]);
            }
        } else {
            $request->query;
        }
        $type = $event['type'];
        $object = $event['data']['object'];
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $today = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('today'));
        switch ($type) {
            case 'checkout.session.completed':
                // Payment is successful and the subscription is created.
                // You should provision the subscription.
                $user->setSubEndDate($today);
                $manager->persist($user);
                $manager->flush();
                break;
            case 'invoice.paid':
                // Continue to provision the subscription as payments continue to be made.
                // Store the status in your database and check when a user accesses your service.
                // This approach helps you avoid hitting rate limits.
                break;
            case 'invoice.payment_failed':
                // The payment failed or the customer does not have a valid payment method.
                // The subscription becomes past_due. Notify your customer and send them to the
                // customer portal to update their payment information.
                break;
            // ... handle other event types
            default:
                // Unhandled event type
        }

        return new JsonResponse([['session'=>$session,'status'=>200]]);
    }
```

when i run`./stripe listen --forward-to https://localhost:8000/bonsai_webhook`
and try to create a subscription i got

```
customer.created [evt_1IYs4HKoLZxEIn3zDY5tFGZV]
2021-03-25 13:13:41            [307] POST http://localhost:8000/bonsai_webhook [evt_1IZ2SeKoLZxEIn3zvx1urxJ1]
```

and in in the webhook route i got  `[{"error":"Unable to extract timestamp and signatures from header","status":403}]`
there is no stripe signature is always empty , and i don't know what i did wrong.

i also added some logs

```php
$logger->info($request->headers->get('stripe-signature'),$request->headers->all());
$logger->error($request->headers->get('stripe-signature'),$request->headers->all());
$logger->critical($request->headers->get('stripe-signature'),$request->headers->all());
```

and i did never receive the logs from the trigger create.subscription.event

so my question is: how to get the stripe signature ? and i hope its the only thing missing in my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing indicates the HTTPS certificate you're using locally isn't recognized as valid by Stripe CLI.

I recommend trying the command with `http://` instead of `https://`:

```
./stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:8000/bonsai_webhook
```

If your web server allows insecure local connections that should get things working.

Comment: i did that but i still have same problem i got `[{"error":"Unable to extract timestamp and signatures from header","status":403}]`
and got this in listener `[307] POST http://localhost:8000/bonsai_webhook [evt_1IZ2SeKoLZxEIn3zvx1urxJ1]`

Comment: Try uncommenting this line: `//$signature = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];`

Comment: Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE"

Comment: Oh, I think Symfony might be preventing the headers from being exposed in the `$_SERVER` variable. Try `$signature = $request->headers->get('Stripe-Signature');` instead.

Comment: yeah, but this is what I did at the beginning. i still have the 307 code

Comment: You may also need to change `$request->query` to `$request->getContent()` in the `constructEvent` method.

Comment: sorry comments are limited in here,suddenly i couldn't answer you, can we chat some where else, if you can help maybe please ? here is my email  : hop.gangnam.style@gmail.com .
for your question yeah, same exact error

Comment: After you do `$signature = $request->headers->get('stripe-signature');` if you log the value of `$signature` what do you see?

Answer (score 1):

In a more recent version of `stripe` (e.g. 1.11.0 and above) the certificate check can be skipped using `--skip-verify`.

So in any case someone is stumble upon the same issue like the author:

```bash
# listen on HTTPS but do not verify SSL/TLS certificate
stripe listen --forward-to https://localhost:8000/bonsai_webhook --skip-verify
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out with the help of the stripe communit, my server was trying to redirect to a https:// URL(that's what the 307 redirect is). Setting https:// in the webhook URL doesn't work because it's a self-signed certificate. And the solution was to disable SSL/HTTPS entirely on the local application, instead i switched to an https environement on a server .

Comment: I'm using the same code and i'm tesing with "http://localhost/webhook"  without https and i'm getting "Unable to extract timestamp and signatures from header"

Comment: yeah, that's the issue bro, it's not gonna work on localhost, you need to go on a secure domain to do that